# Oracle PHP Inserting Large Amount of Rows

Tags: php, oracle

I have tried searching around and couldn't find anything that helped me.

Basically I query this database and get some results (~4000 rows).
I then load these results into an array with `oci_fetch_array()`.

Then I try and insert these values into another database

```
foreach ($full_output as $row) {

$counter++;
$sql_values .= "INTO DATA (ID, STARTDATE, CITY) VALUES (".$counter.", TO_DATE('".$row['STARTDATE']."', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '".$row['CITY']."')\n";

if ($counter % 1000 == 0 || $counter == $numrows) {
// inserts every 1000 values
$sql = "INSERT ALL\n".$sql_values."SELECT * FROM dual";
//function that just parses and executes statement
parse_and_query($conn, $sql);
$sql_values ='';
}
}

function parse_and_query($conn,$sql)
{
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
if (!$stid) { $e = oci_error($conn); print htmlentities($e['message']); exit; }
$r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
if (!$r) { $e = oci_error($stid); echo htmlentities($e['message']); exit; }

return $stid;
}
```

This works fine, however it takes around 10 minutes to execute. I've tried using `bind_by_name` but I cannot get it to work.

Do you guys know by any chance of a more efficient way of inserting in oracle? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The general answers are:

Use bind variables otherwise you are causing a lot of statement parsing in the DB and are unable to reuse data structures.

Avoid committing on each INSERT (you already have this figured out).  Do:

```
$s = oci_parse($c, 'insert into ptab (pdata) values (:bv)');
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':bv', $v, 20, SQLT_CHR);
foreach ($a as $v) {
    $r = oci_execute($s, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);  // Use alias OCI_DEFAULT in older OCI8 versions
}
oci_commit($c);
```

Use oci_bind_array_by_name() where possible. Something like:

```
$a = array('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl');
$s = oci_parse($c, "begin mypkg.myinsproc(:a); end;"); 
oci_bind_array_by_name($s, ":a", $a, count($a), -1, SQLT_CHR); 
oci_execute($s);
```

(See p.195 of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html )

Or faster still for big datasets is to use Python cx_Oracle, Node.js node-oracledb, JDBC or OCI which have a batch insertion API e.g. https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you know if I could use one bind variable for my whole VALUES statement or does each value need to have a separate bind variable?

Comment: You are inserting into 3 columns so you need 3 bind variables.